# Nameservers conflict with domain and subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I am looking to have my primary domain name use a different nameserver than the nameservers my subdomain services are using. For instance:

***abc.com*** => NS1.bluehost.com

***remote.abc.com*** => NS1.thirdparty.com, NS2.thirdparty.com

***virtual.abc.com*** => NS1.thirdparty.com, NS2.thirdparty.com

The first domain I would like to connect to a specific nameserver where hosting for the site is.

The other 2 subdomains I would like to forward to a third party service.

I need the domain name to load up a website off a host while the subdomains still maintaining access to the services they are currently connected to.

**What I've Tried:**

Creating a list compiling all the nameservers I needed, but that led to faulty connections.

Using a CNAME to point, but then it creates a wildcard, forwarding all subdomains as well.

**Things to consider:**

I believe I could just set up the website if I had access to the same hosting the nameservers the subdomains are linked too, but because it is a third party service, access is prohibited. So the nameservers of the subdomains must stay intact for those services.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your domain abc.com is controlled on (i.e. control delegated to) NS1.bluehost.com, then all subdomain delegations or any other DNS sub-name controlling should be done on that nameserver.

You don't have to delegate control on dns subdomains to other servers if you just want to host your sub-name web sites on other hosting service provider. In this case you only need to set up A records for sub-names pointing to that other hosting web servers, and leave their dns hosting abilities unused.

If delegating sub-domains is what you really need, read further.

To delegate, records you have to add there will look like this:

```
virtual.abc.com. NS NS1.thirdparty.com.
remote.abc.com. NS NS2.thirdparty.com.
```

How to do this depends on how you supposed to control records in abc.com. For example, this could be as easy as add new resource records of type NS in bluehost.com dns control panel, or there could be "tab" named "subdomain delegations" in the dns control, or something like this.

NS1.thirdparty.com and NS2.thirdparty.com should be prepared to have control on their zones.

After this, any changes of remote.abc.com or anything.remove.abc.com should be done on NS2.thirdparty.com.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and concise response, this helped very much. I will give it a shot, but I believe this was the response I was looking for.

Comment: @silas_newbie : my answer still applies after your question edit. Just double NS records for each name: virtual.abc.com. NS NS1.thirdparty.com. // virtual.abc.com. NS NS2.thirdparty.com. // etc. and it will get delegated to both servers (assuming they're in sync).